# Interface orientation to Landscape only

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

In my view controller i have this function implemented:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

but my viewcontroller doesn't switch its orientation. What am i missing? thanks

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on that line, does it ever hit?

Answer (score 0):

I do it with:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||  interfaceOrientation ==  UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Which is basically what you are doing. Make sure InterfaceBuilder have your views on Landscape mode also.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this but doesn't work. I don't have a nib, everything is done programmatically so.